Customizing label frequency of waterway river layer obtained by QuickOSM in QGIS
River labels of a 'waterway_river' layer obtained by QuickOSM are most of the time too redundant per river (see Image 1). You can reduce the number of labels with the label rendering option "Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels" (see Image 2). But this appears to be inconsistent and sometimes all labels of a river are gone or just outside in the masked area.
Is there a smart rule-based labelling process to customize the number of labels per river from 1 to 3?



Use the "Dissolve" tool using the river name field as the dissolve field then use the resulting layer for labelling.
As the resulting layer will only have one feature par river name you will be able to control the position of the labels and their repetition in an easier way.

I tried this already. However, for some rivers the label was outside inn the masked area

@Schorsch you may clip the labelling layer so you got only river in the unmasked area

I just tried the clip tool for the first time. Very nice result as you predicted. The label placement along the river still seems to be kind of random. I can move the label, but only up to a certain point.

Labelling is always a pain to get right, for a few label on a static map it seem that manually placing the label is still the simplest/fastest way to get good results...

You are right. I could move nearly all labels to a desired place except for one. Overall your advice let to a good end-result. Many thanks.
